# Istio: privileged scc on openshift

Tags: openshift, istio

According to [quickstart guide](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start/#openshift-origin), it's mandatory to grant `privileged` scc to service account in order to be able to run istio.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z <target service account> -n <target-namespace>
```

My question is, why do I need to grant `privileged`?

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm assuming something in there must run as root ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Actually, those instructions need to be updated a bit.

But for this tutorial specifically, we need to relax some of openshift's security policies (not intended for a real production environment) because the Istio init container requires access to the NET_ADMIN capabilities to configure the iptables redirection for the sidecar proxies. The sidecar proxies don't need this level of capability, but the init container does.

HTH